# Core data + iCloud: exclude certain attributes from sync?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, synchronization, icloud

I am trying to implement core data sync using iCloud. However, there is one attribute that I don't want to sync. Is there a proper way to tell iCloud to sync most managed objects and attributes, but not others?

Answer (score 2):

Right now, Core Data + iCloud does not support this kind of configuration. You may have to split your Data into two Persistent Stores (lokal, cloud).

Comment: What is the best way to do this with an existing data set? If I want to take an existing attribute and move it to a new (totally local) persistent store, how should I do this to migrate existing users?

Comment: Create a new persistent store (totally local), migrate the data you want to this store and remove it from the cloud store. -- On app start check if the local store exists, if not, create it and do the migration.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to add the things you do not wish to sync to an entity that includes a unique device identifier.

In this way, they still get synced, but you can use just the data pertinent to the specific device and ignore the data from other devices.