# Syncing only "some" of my coreData over iCloud

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

So my situation is I'm developing an application that will will be recording track data from both GPS and an external sensor.  Each recording will be tied to a **User** and a **Vehicle** profile.  As the recordings themselves can get rather large I was hoping to sync the Profile Information (**User Info** / and **Vehicle Info**) with iCloud while keeping the actual **track recording** data un-synched.

Is there a way to do this with a **single persistent data store** or do I need to create 2 stores and have 1 on iCloud and one local?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need two persistent stores, one for the un-synced data and one for the synced data. This is a good use case for Configurations in your data model.

You'll probably want the User/Vehicle info in both stores, because you can't have relationships between objects in two different persistent stores.

See [Syncing core data with iCloud - excluding entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834654/syncing-core-data-with-icloud-excluding-entities) for more info.